# How to get the value of state inside the function in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have problem right now where the state can't access inside on my function so the type of error is: **Cannot read the property of start_date of undefined.** I have module where I need to filter based on the date range selected. Now I have parent and child component, Where I send the selected range to the children. Now inside of my children I set the props selected range to my state. When I try to console logs the state it says that start_date is undefined. I will show you guys my parent component and my children component.

Error:

> Cannot read the property of start_date of undefined

[image: Error]

Parent Component:

```
<Grap  selected_range={this.state.selectionRange}/>
```

Children Component:

```
this.state = {
            start_date:''
}

dataDate = () => {

    

        var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
    
        var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
    
        var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);
        
        var month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    
        var dDate = []
    

        var startDate = this.state.start_date.startDate;
        

        var now = new Date();
        for (var d = new Date(startDate); d <= now; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
            var date = new Date(d);
            let formatted_date = month[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate();
            dDate.push(formatted_date);
        }
       
        return dDate
    
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        
        this.setState({
            start_date:this.props.selected_range
        })


    }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(this.state.start_date !== this.props.selected_range) {
           
            this.setState({
                start_date: this.props.selected_range
            })
        }        
    }
```

I call the function of dataDate inside of object:

```
data = {

    labels: this.dataDate(),
    datasets: [
       
        {

            label: 'Receive Check',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(195 218 251 / 35%)',
            borderColor: '#70a8f3',
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: '2',
            fill: true,
            lineTension: 0.0,
            pointRadius: 7,
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: this.randomVal(),
        }
    ]
};
```

start_date value:

[image: values]

Comment: Where do you call the function?

Comment: @BrianThompson hi I update my content.

Answer (score 0):

```
In your children component, 
this.state = {
            start_date:''
}

type of start date is string. You can't access property on string.
Define it something like this.state = {
            start_date: {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.start_date` declare in the same form that we receive from prop.

```
this.state = {
  start_date: {
    endDate : new Date(),
    startDate : new Date(),
    key : ''
  
  }
  
}
```

The reason for doing this is because react see '' before it is mounted for the first time, resulting in an error.
You'd better take a look at the `lifecycle` again.
and take a `moment` library to help you with dateformat.

Comment: even I formatted it like that, I can't call state inside the function

Comment: If you want a better answer, more code line plz